# Javascript tree-view programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, treeview

I want to implement a tree view using [this](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-family-tree) solution with data supplied from server.

So far I've implemented a simple javascript solution ([plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/XCGqUgEuRtanXysxt1fd?p=preview)). Problem is, I really have no idea why the '2.1' child element is added under '1' node - even the console.logs are showing correct trace info.

I'm having a recursive function to render all the nodes:

```
var putManyInGraph = function(where, list, level) {
    where.append(levelTemplate.render(level));
    list.forEach(function(item){
        var lvl = $("#level-"+level);
        lvl.append(childTemplate.render(item.label));
        if(item.children && item.children.length > 0) {
            putManyInGraph($("#level-"+level + " li:last"), item.children, level + 1);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not working because you are creating duplicate ids.  Inspect the tree and you see this:

[image: duplicate ids]

Don't even mess with ids.  Instead, just keep a reference to the element when you create it.

```
var putManyInGraph = function (where, list, level) {
    var lvl = $(levelTemplate.render(level)).appendTo(where);
    list.forEach(function (item) {
        var li = $(childTemplate.render(item.label)).appendTo(lvl);
        if (item.children && item.children.length > 0) {
            putManyInGraph(li, item.children, level + 1);
        }
    });
};
```

[Updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uYQSITM7G0P2qHEwIh5q?p=preview)